# Objective-C gzipped NSData to Python gzipped string?

Tags: python, objective-c, nsstring, gzip, nsdata

I'm using [+[NSData gtm_dataByGzippingData:]](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSData%2Bzlib.h?r=517#40) to gzip the UTF-8 encoded data returned by `+[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]`.

How do I convert this gzipped `NSData` to a string that I can send as a parameter to a Python server so that the server can decompress it with [zlib.decompress()](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress)?

Answer (score 1):

Use a method like [`-[NSData base64EncodedString]`](https://github.com/venmo/venmo-ios-sdk/blob/master/Venmo/Private/VenmoBase64.m#L24-53) to base64-encode the gzipped `NSData` before you send it to the Python server.

Then, the Python server can base64-decode it and then unzip it like so:

```
contacts_data = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(contacts_base64), 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the header file that you referenced in your question, deflate is NOT gzip.  Gzip is a file structure, where as zlib is more of a compression stream.

First, I'd recommend that you change your code to use...

```
+ (NSData *)gtm_dataByDeflatingData:(NSData *)data;
```

So, now you have the compressed data.  How are you sending it to the server?  Are you pushing this over HTTP?  Is it a custom service with a direct socket connection?  Can you send 8-bit bytes, are are you restricted to sending 7-bit bytes? ...are you using NURLConnection?  ...are  you trying to upload the (compressed) data as a file via HTTP?